# Returning a list from controller to javascript causes a 406

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to send a json list from the controller to the javascript when the given URL is accessed. With this code, I am receiving a 406 error when I go to the URL. My servlet context has `<annotation-driven />` and I have the `org.codehaus.jackson` maven dependencies. Is there any other reason this is giving me a 406, or is there a better way to go about sending a list to the javascript?

Controller Function

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{room}/handhygiene.json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ArrayList<Integer> getHandHygienePageAsync(
            @PathVariable(value = "room") String roomCode) {
        ArrayList<Integer> json = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Room room = getRoom(roomCode);

        json.add(service.getHandHygieneEvents(room));
        if (room.isGroupBased()) {
            json.add(service.getRoomEntryExits(room));
        }
        if (room.isIdBased()) {
            json.add(service.getPatientContacts(room));
        }
        return json;
    }
```

Javascript

```
$.getJSON(currentURL + ".json",
            function(data){
                alert('I can\'t get here though');
                var overallRatio;
                var handWash = data[0];

                $("#handwash").html(handWash);
                if(groupBased == true)
                {
                    var enex = data[1];
                    $("#enex").html(enex);
                    overallRatio = "" + Math.round((handWash*100)/enex) + "%";
                }
                else
                {
                    if(idBased == true)
                    {
                        var contacts = data[2];
                        $("#contacts").html(contacts);
                        overallRatio = "" + Math.round((handWash*100)/contacts) + "%";                      
                    }
                }

                $("#overall").html(overallRatio);

            }
    );
```

Here's the headers for the request

```
GET /groupbased/ICU6/handhygiene.json HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.152 Safari/537.22
Referer: http://localhost:8080/groupbased/ICU6/handhygiene
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: JSESSIONID=063CDE4BF5FB7369B6C48FC2EADFD8E9
```

---

Would this view resolver conflict with anything?

```
@Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
```

Comment: For the error code: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html

Comment: What version of Spring? Are you using a mapper dependency like jackson-mapper-asl? Are you using a content negotiating view resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Add below config to mvc-servet.xml

```
<bean name="customViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
    <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/config/spring/customViews.xml" />
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

Create below customViews.xml in the path /WEB-INF/config/spring/customViews.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
      "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>
<bean name="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.JsonView"/>    
</beans>
```

controller change:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{room}/handhygiene.json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getHandHygienePageAsync(
        @PathVariable(value = "room") String roomCode,ModelMap model) {
    ArrayList<Integer> json = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Room room = getRoom(roomCode);

    json.add(service.getHandHygieneEvents(room));
    if (room.isGroupBased()) {
        json.add(service.getRoomEntryExits(room));
    }
    if (room.isIdBased()) {
        json.add(service.getPatientContacts(room));
    }
    model.addAttribute("json",json)
    return "jsonView";
}
```

Feel free to mark it as answer and to click uplink, if this solved your problem.